# What does "Listed Only" mean on German financial platforms?

Tags: stocks, trading, stock-markets, germany

When I'm looking at EFS, Funds and Stocks in the German market I alway see (and always only in English, surrounded by German words) "Listed Only" on all these exchanges.

What do they mean? What is the implication? Why is it there? Am I prevented from trading with these exchanges?

Here are some I saw on websites:

[example link 1](https://bluewin.mdgms.com/detail/stocks?ID_NOTATION=36663730)
[example link 2](https://www.comdirect.de/inf/aktien/detail/uebersicht.html?ID_NOTATION=36663730&ID_NOTATION_INDEX=10407783&INDEX_FILTER=true)

[image]
[image]

Here's one from inside Commerzbank's trading platform:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BATS and NYSE ARCA are considered MTFs ([multilateral trading facility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilateral_trading_facility)) under MiFID II.

The "listed only" seems to refer to the type of order routing. I believe it means your order will only be re-routed to listed exchanges like NYSE and NASDAQ, as opposed to dark pools and other trading venues.

For a definitive answer, I'd suggest calling your broker's support, e.g. Commerzbank.